# Quarkus Amazon SQS client with message listener

Tags: java, amazon-sqs, quarkus

For Quarkus there is an extension for AMAZON SQS: https://quarkus.io/extensions/io.quarkiverse.amazonservices/quarkus-amazon-sqs. I followed documentation guide to configure producer and consumer of messages (https://docs.quarkiverse.io/quarkus-amazon-services/dev/amazon-sqs.html). But in that example, consumption of message is triggered by GET method:

```
@GET
    public List<Quark> receive() {
        List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(m -> m.maxNumberOfMessages(10).queueUrl(queueUrl)).messages();

        return messages.stream()
                .map(Message::body)
                .map(this::toQuark)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Is there any way to make this extension to trigger message read as soon as it comes to the consumer (like in other message brokers e.g. RabbitMQ)? Spring has annotation @SqsListener, but quarkus unfortunately lacks it. I understand that I can use loop to check, but it is very bad for performance.
Thank you in advance for any suggestions

Also I know that there is a library for AMAZON SQS on pure java (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/getting-started.html) which seems to have such capability, but it is too low-level and I'd prefer to avoid using it.